# inregularity in attrs odoo10

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

Hello friends I have a button in odoo which I want to be invisible when the 3 conditions are met:

```
<button class="oe_highlight"  name="formview" type="object" string="Pagar" attrs="{'invisible':['|',('status_inv', '=',2),('validate_cheque', '=',False),('pay', '=',True)]}"/>
```

I have the invisible attribute in this way but it does not behave well.

if I replace it | by & odoo gives an error finally what I want is that it behaves like the AND operator if the 3 is fulfilled that is invisible

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<button class="oe_highlight"  name="formview" type="object" string="Pagar" attrs="{'invisible':[('status_inv', '=',2),('validate_cheque', '=',False),('pay', '=',True)]}"/>
```

If no operator is declared, the '&' operator is put by default.

Comment: at the beginning try this but the behavior is not appropriate, because if at least 1 is fulfilled the bottom is shown and I want the condition (necessary) to be when the 3 conditions are strictly met this hidden the example button (if status_inv == 2 and validate_cheque = = false and pay = = True then the answer is {invisible})

Comment: For me it's normal is only one is fulfilled that the bottom is shown. To be invisible, with the domain I given, the three conditions should be fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
A = ('status_inv') == False
B = (validate_cheque) False
C = ('payment') True
A and B == false
False and C == False
```

And look, you still see the bottom and you should not